# How to use useState in useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I try to refacto my compoenent from react.component to hooks but I got some troubles. I don't really understand how to use my state `offsetTop`. The value is set, or not when I need.

First try:

```
const [offsetTop, setOffsetTop] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    setOffsetTop(window.pageYOffset + document.querySelector(".projectsContainer").getBoundingClientRect().top)
    console.log(offsetTop);
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, true)
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
}, []);
```

I also tried to use it with a second method `useEffect` with `[offsetTop]` as a second parameters  but my log showed up twice with undef and the value. I understand why it shows twice, but still doesn't solve my problem, my condition does not work.

Second try:

```
const [offsetTop, setOffsetTop] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    setOffsetTop(window.pageYOffset + document.querySelector(".projectsContainer").getBoundingClientRect().top)
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(offsetTop);
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, true)
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
}, [offsetTop]);
```

handleScroll function :

```js
function handleScroll() {
    console.log(offsetTop);
    const scrolledY = window.scrollY
    if (scrolledY > offsetTop) console.log("works")
}
```

The same code as the `First try:`  placed in `componentDidMount() {}` and using `this` works fine. So it is not the condition that is bad. It's about when the value is set and how `useState` and `useEffect` works.

Comment: are you sure `.projectsContainer` is available to be queried when the useEffect runs? To ensure it is you can try [`useLayoutEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) instead, which runs synchronously after all DOM mutations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't your condition work in the first variant? That one looks correct, and `console.log(offsetTop)` in that case is not supposed to print the newly set value, but the previously set value. To log it like you want you need:

```js
const [offsetTop, setOffsetTop] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    setOffsetTop(window.pageYOffset + document.querySelector(".projectsContainer").getBoundingClientRect().top)
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, true)
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(offsetTop);
}, [offsetTop]);
```

The problem with your second try is that it does the following:

- First render:

  - 1st useEffect sets new `offsetTop`
  - 2nd useEffect fires with old `offsetTop`
- `offsetTop` update causes re-render

  - 2nd useEffect does clean-up, removing the event listener
  - I guess, somewhere here browser propagates event, with your listener gone
  - 2nd useEffect fires second time, with new `offsetTop`, and sets your listener again (but it already missed the event)

Ah... that's only a part of your problem.

The second part of your problem is that `handleScroll()` effectively captures `offsetTop` value from the render cycle where it was created and set as the listener. You should use `useRef()` to keep `handleScroll()` in-sync with the current value (and if you don't need `offsetTop` for other reasons, you don't need to use the state at all. You can do:

```js
const { current: heap } = useRef({
  offsetTop: 0,
});

useEffect(() => {
  function handleScroll() {
    console.log(heap.offsetTop);
    const scrolledY = window.scrollY
    if(scrolledY > heap.offsetTop) console.log("works")
  }
  heap.offsetTop = window.pageYOffset + document.querySelector(".projectsContainer").getBoundingClientRect().top;
  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, true)
  return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  // The heap is guaranteed to be the same object across re-renders,
  // thus including it into dependencies below does not cause useEffect
  // to recompute. However, if you don't include it, and rely on ESLint
  // to check code errors, it will complain about heap not being there
  // as missing dependency.
}, [heap]);
```

This way, `offsetTop` is persistent across re-renders, and `handleScroll()` always uses the current value. And if you need also re-render on `offsetTop` updates, then you can additionally use `useState()` to trigger re-renders (say to also inject `offsetTop` values into rendered components.

Answer (score 3):

This strikes me as a case where you may not need state at all. Why not derive the value of `offsetTop` as needed?

```
useEffect(() => {
  function handleScroll() {
    const scrolledY = window.scrollY;
    const offsetTop = window.pageYOffset + document.querySelector(".projectsContainer").getBoundingClientRect().top;
    if(scrolledY > offsetTop) console.log("works")
  }

  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, true)
  return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, true);
}, []);
```

---

However, maybe the idea is that you want to capture the initial value of `offsetTop` and then use it as things change. In that case, I think your main problem is due to `removeEventListener` not being cleaned up correctly because you're not passing the same parameters as those given to `addEventListener` (missing `true`). Because of that, there is still an instance of `handleScroll` holding the initial value of `offsetTop` from the first render, and I think that's why you're seeing `undefined` being logged.

### Wrong ❌

```
useEffect(() => {
  setOffsetTop(window.pageYOffset +
      document.querySelector(".projectsContainer").getBoundingClientRect().top;);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  // The first time this useEffect runs, the value of `offsetTop`
  // is still the initial value of undefined.
  function handleScroll() {
    console.log(offsetTop)
    const scrolledY = window.scrollY;
    if (scrolledY > offsetTop) console.log("works");
  }

  window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, true);
  // This doesn't get removed correctly
  // because you don't pass the same parameters (missing `true`)
  return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll); 
}, [offsetTop]);
```

### Right ✅

```
useEffect(() => {
  setOffsetTop(window.pageYOffset +
      document.querySelector(".projectsContainer").getBoundingClientRect().top;);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  function handleScroll() {
    const scrolledY = window.scrollY;
    if (scrolledY > offsetTop) console.log("works");
  }

  window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, true);
  return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, true);
}, [offsetTop]);
```

**Reproduction:** https://codesandbox.io/s/so-67247616-pl455

Comment: Your right variant has that problem: it removes and re-adds event listener on each update of `offsetTop`, which is bad performance-wise, also will miss some updates in-between (when the previous listener is removed, but the new is not added yet).

Good point that params of `removeEventListener(..)` must match those of `addEventListener(..)` - I missed that :)